# Passing form input data to the mail view - Laravel

Tags: php, forms, email, laravel

I am making a form which will send an email.

Currently its a generic blade form which points to /admin/newemail

I have my route and for testing the mail is sent from that route:

```
Route::get('admin/newemail', function()
{
    $email = 'email@hotmail.com';
    $data = Input::all();
    Mail::send('emails.newemail', $data, function($message) use ($email){
        // $message details
    });
});
```

And then to trial this I tried in my view: (there is a field name of 'subject' in my form)

```
echo Input::get("subject");
```

I actually have two issues. (I am using the log driver)

1) The email is not showing in the log, its just showing [] [] 
2) The data is not showing neither and its blank.

If I simply have:

```
echo "hello!";
```

Then the log will output hello, likewise If i change my mail data variable to an array:

```
$data = array('test' => 'test');
```

Then in the view:

```
echo $test;
```

That also works. But I want it to take my inputs from my form.

Comment: What `method` are you using for your `<form>`? Post you form code. If the form data is not getting posted back to the server then the problem might come from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Try this:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', array('key' => 'value'), function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Here, key will be any name which you want to give and value will be the data you want to assign, it could be form data or could be from database.

Now, after doing that create a file in your views/emails as welcome.blade.php and to fetch the value passed through mail function use:

```
{{ $key }}
```

Above is the blade format to represent data.

For more info on mail, visit [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail), and for blade templates go [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates).

See, if that helps you.

Comment: Thats the same example as I gave in my question. I can hardcode the array fine, but I want all the input from a form available in the view.

Comment: Try: $data = Input::only('element1', 'element2', 'element3'), then pass that array in your mail function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', Input::all(), function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

and in your view you have

```
{{Input::get("subject")}}
```

This is what i use myself and it works perfectly.